# Rethinkdb insert into nested array

Tags: rethinkdb

I want to add to an array nested inside a table, appending a new item to the array.

But the returned run query is undefined. Please can anyone suggest a better way to run this?

```
rdb.table('SavedBaskets').get(basketId).run().then(function(result) {
            let newPaymentHistory = [];
            if ('paymentHistory' in result) {
                newPaymentHistory = result.paymentHistory;
            }
            paymentHistory.push(charge);
            return rdb.table('SavedBaskets').get(basketId).update({paymentHistory: newPaymentHistory}).run();
        }).error(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Comment: charge is just an external variable inserted into the code @Kludge

Comment: In line `paymentHistory.push(charge);`, `paymentHistory` is undefined. Try changing it to `newPaymentHistory`, which is your new value IIUC

Answer (score 1):

You could use *.append()* such as

```
r.table("SavedBaskets").get(basketId).update(
     {"paymentHistory": r.row("paymentHistory").append(charge)}
).run(conn)
```

https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/append/

Seen here

http://docs.rethinkdb.com/2.0/api/python/update/